# Best public Hadoop AMI for Hadoop version 1.0.0

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, ec2-ami

I tried to find a good public Hadoop AMI (1.0.0 or 1.0.1) but couldn't. If it contains PIG by default, it will be even better. It looks like Cloudera Hadoop distribution seems to be what I should try but I am not sure what to use. Please advise.